# Applescript comparison stopped working

Tags: if-statement, applescript

I have a script that does a cURL request and returns a string if no database rows are found.  At one point this was working and then all the sudden it stopped working.

```
set testURL to the quoted form of ("http:/  
set theURL to (do shell script "curl " & testURL & "")  

if theURL = "no rows" then  

    display dialog "error"  
    error number -128 

else  
     display dialog("success")  
end if
```

when i display the veriable setURL it always comes back "no rows" and the comparison never works.  It skips over the error message and skips right to success no matter what.  What is this and why did my comparison stop working all of the sudden? I have tried everything from trying to set it as a string to different ways of saying the same thing and it never works.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete, does not compile and cannot be tested as is! If you want help debugging code then the question should conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it's subject to getting down-votes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the result contains some whitespace.

Try

- `theURL contains "no rows"`
- `theURL starts with "no rows"`
- `theURL ends with "no rows"`

By the way: Why do you append an empty string to your `do shell script` line?

Comment: So my problem is that I have a lot of applications already using my existing code so it would be exhausting to change all of them to theURL contains "no rows".  I am not sure what you are referring to when you say empty string to my shell script?